# Как затолкнуть форму в template tags?

Tags: django

Есть форма.
Как передать ее в урл это понятно. А как передать ее в темплейт теги?

Ведь форме нужен урл, куда отправлять информацию ПОСТ.

Нужно для формы обратной связи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без представления вы форму никак не обработаете. Сделайте отдельное представление для формы и отправляйте аяксом или редиректите после обработки куда нужно.

А форму можно добавлять в базовом шаблоне через свой тег:

```
@register.assigment_tag()
def get_form():
    return FormFoo()
```

HTML

```
{% get_form as form %}
<form action={% url 'form_view' %}>
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Привет! Он возвращает
    <callback.views.FormFoo object at 0x011AEBF0>

Comment: Соответственно, это же вью привязываем к урлу, на который будем отправлять и получать запросы?

Comment: а кто он? и при каких условиях? вью отдает html или json с информацией обработки формы

Comment: выше приведенный код. {{ form }} выводит <callback.views.FormFoo object at 0x011AEBF0>

Comment: как обработать object, который передаем в template

Comment: Попробуйте {{ form.as_p }}, объект FooForm должен быть подклассом Form или ModelForm. А вью вы привязываете к урлу имя которого указываете в теге url.

Comment: Мне тут подсказали.

Comment: Joe Doe, [04.11.16 18:10]
Честно. Я вообще не понимаю, зачем ради 3х строк городить миксины.

Joe Doe, [04.11.16 18:11]
Пишите cbv. В тег отдавайте простенькую функцию, и на шаблоне 3 строки js